# What happens, if I accidentally don't dispose the Entity Framework context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Let's assume a simple ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var db = new SomeDataContext(); // without 'using' or 'await using'
        var models = db.Models.ToList();
        return this.View(models)
    }
}
```

What exactly happens, if I forget about the [using-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)? Will the context never expose? Will it leak memory? Is it really a deadly sin?

Comment: It can leak an open connection, and eventually lead to connection pool starvation, of which there are many posts on [so], see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261113/timeout-error-in-ado-net-with-connection-pooling. Eventually they usually get disposed by the GC, but this can take some time (if ever) and is often not fast enough to avoid starvation. Does it actually cost to have a `using` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will leave an open database connection, as well as keep memory allocated for all tracked instances until garbage collection works out that the references are all not in use and actually releases them.

So if your Models table has 100k rows:

```
    var db = new SomeDataContext(); // +1 connection from the connection pool when first query is run.
    var models = db.Models.ToList(); // +100k loaded entities.
```

Testing this as a single user you're not going to see that much unless you start looking at your memory usage... Deploy that onto a web server that has 100+ users that make concurrent requests and watch your web server grind itself into oblivion.

Also, avoid returning Entities to the view, project just the data you need into a ViewModel/DTO using `Select()` or Automapper's `ProjectTo()`. (*don't* use Automapper's `Map()`) Not only does this avoid pitfalls like lazy-load hits for related data, but also produces more efficient / faster queries.

Always dispose of your DbContext instances. This means either use `using` blocks or set up dependency injection to manage the lifetime scope of an injected DbContext, scoped to Per HTTP Request for web sites/services.

Comment: Will smth like Garbage Collection (or finalizers) will ever close the connection to the database?

Comment: Eventually, probably... Certainly when your application pool cycles because of an exception... : )  Ultimately there is no reason *not* to set up the DbContext to be managed by an IoC container servicing the web site and managing the scope of the context instance to the HTTP Request.  It's not really a question worth asking "what if I don't do that" but rather understanding how to do it properly to avoid facing problems down the road.